# Too many alphabets using siunitx

Tags: xetex, siunitx

I'm getting this annoying error when I try using some features of siunitx package. Let's say I want to make a simple table:

```
 \begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption for the table.}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{l|c||r}
    1 & 2 & 3 \si{\volt}\\
    \hline
    a & b & c\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

If I would use command `\si{\volt}` there would be no error. But if I would use `\SI{3}{\volt}` instead, I would get an error. Do you have any idea what is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Which document class do you use, and which packages that utilize additional math fonts do you load in your document? The reason I ask is that I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe if I prefix `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{siunitx} \begin{document}` and affix `\end{document}` to your code in order to make it (minimally) compilable.

Comment: The whole definition comes from a class file. Inside it the class is defined as article.

Comment: There are lots and lots of LaTeX document classes out there that are based loosely on the `article` class. To have a chance to solve the issue you're experiencing, it's crucial to know *which* class file is loaded by your document.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. If you want to write:

```
\RequirePackage{ifplatform}
\ifwindows
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,ItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-LightItalic,BoldFont=RobotoCondensed-Regular,BoldItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-Italic]{RobotoCondensed-Light}
  \setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{RobotoMono-Light} 
  \setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){RobotoCondensed-Light}
  \setmathrm[ItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-LightItalic,BoldFont=RobotoCondensed-Regular,BoldItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-Italic]{RobotoCondensed-Light}
\else
  \setmainfont[BoldFont=Roboto Condensed, BoldItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Italic,ItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Light Italic,Ligatures=TeX]{Roboto Condensed Light}
  \setmonofont[Scale=.9]{Roboto Mono Light} 
  \setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){Roboto Condensed Light}
  \setmathrm[ItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Light Italic,BoldFont=Roboto Condensed,BoldItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Italic]{Roboto Condensed Light}
\fi
```

It will not work. However, if you write:

```
\RequirePackage{ifplatform}
\ifwindows
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,ItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-LightItalic,BoldFont=RobotoCondensed-Regular,BoldItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-Italic]{RobotoCondensed-Light}
    \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,ItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-LightItalic,BoldFont=RobotoCondensed-Regular,BoldItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-Italic]{RobotoCondensed-Light}
    \setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{RobotoMono-Light} 
    \setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){RobotoCondensed-Light}
    \setmathrm[ItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-LightItalic,BoldFont=RobotoCondensed-Regular,BoldItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-Italic]{RobotoCondensed-Light}
    \setmathsf[ItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-LightItalic,BoldFont=RobotoCondensed-Regular,BoldItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-Italic]{RobotoCondensed-Light}
\else
    \setmainfont[BoldFont=Roboto Condensed, BoldItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Italic,ItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Light Italic,Ligatures=TeX]{Roboto Condensed Light}
    \setsansfont[BoldFont=Roboto Condensed, BoldItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Italic,ItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Light Italic,Ligatures=TeX]{Roboto Condensed Light}
    \setmonofont[Scale=.9]{Roboto Mono Light} 
    \setmathfont(Greek,Digits,Latin){Roboto Condensed Light}
    \setmathrm[ItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Light Italic,BoldFont=Roboto Condensed,BoldItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Italic]{Roboto Condensed Light}
    \setmathsf[ItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Light Italic,BoldFont=Roboto Condensed,BoldItalicFont=Roboto Condensed Italic]{Roboto Condensed Light}
\fi
```

I am guessint that the last command in second code block is important. However I cannot find what does `\setmathsf` does.

Comment: Please consider augmenting your code snippet into a standalone, compilable LaTeX document. Without this additional information, it's nearly impossible to tell what's going on.